# REST - sending user ID vs picking up user ID from Principal

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security

I would like to know the right approach to defining a RESTful service for a generic use case.

I am writing a RESTful API to update the current user's profile. Should we send current user's ID within the request? This would require validation on server side such that user can only edit his own details. So I would need to add check on user ID and Principal object. Also, the client side has to maintain current user ID somewhere.

```
POST /user/{id}
```

Alternatively, I can just skip sending the user ID and fetch the user details from Principal object. As we know there is nothing like *stateless secured* API, would it be the right approach?

I am not aware of any feature in Spring that would validate the current user for me, as required in first approach. If it is present then please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the case where an administrator, who is authorized to update other users, wants to send the update. In this case, it would be to `POST /user/{id}`. There's no reason that this shouldn't also be the case for an ordinary user.

With Spring Security, you can use an `@PreAuthorize` expression on your controller method. It would look something like this:

```
@PostMapping("/user/{id}")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN') || (principal.id == #id)")
public User updateUser(@RequestBody User newInfo, @PathVariable Long id) {
    ...
}
```